# Header files inclusion and performance considerations c++

Tags: c++, c, include

Assuming all headers have include guards set appropriately, are there any means of improving run time performance of an application by simply altering these headers?

Is there any difference, performance wise, between an application that has all the needed headers in one file and an application that doesn't?

Comment: Run-time efficiency?  Headers affect compilation time, but they really don't affect run-time efficiency of the compiled code (application).

Comment: Please, please, for the sake of all that is good in software development, don't go around thinking completely irrelevant random changes make a difference for performance. Let me turn the question around: why do you think it would?

Comment: (I think you answering that question would help you more because it would allow us to dispel whatever misconceptions you currently hold)

Comment: I thought no matter how you included the header files, their content would eventually be injected into your files somewhere and the linker would link them appropriately? Why not try it and benchmark the results?

Comment: "by simply altering these headers?"  No, the only runtime performance improvement I can think of that is built on `#include` is a unity build, and that requires makefile changes, not simply alterations to headers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: We live in a world of complicated CPU architectures, where seemingly "irrelevant random changes" CAN make a difference in performance.  Consider the case where changing a local variable somewhere in the call stack causes the stack to be 8 byte aligned instead of 16 byte aligned.  SSE code completely unrelated to the change will suffer.  Changes in memory layout, which affect cache performance, can also lead to "action at a distance".

Comment: @BenVoigt my point still stands: if you have no reason to suspect a difference, and no test case showing one (hence the "random" bit), why are you worrying?

Comment: @ Ben Voigt Right on the money. It seems that such "irrelevant changes" are often overlooked due to "common sense".

Comment: Test it. Check the performance difference by moving as much as you can into one file.

Comment: @Sebi: Which is why you need to use some understanding of what's going on... which this question certainly does not.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt I pretty much understand what's going on :) . I simply wanted to know if performance can be increased in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Run-time efficiency

The sets of headers included or not included really have no effect on the efficiency of the resulting application at run time.  You should include the headers that declare the functions you use.  If those headers provide inline function definitions, for example, then you may get some performance boost by comparison with (hypothetical alternative) headers that don't provide inline function declarations, but you still need to include the header so that is controlled by the people providing the headers.

#### Compile-time efficiency

*I first assumed this was what you're after, in part because of the mention of header include guards which are a purely compilation-related issue.*

If the headers are set up with include guards, you can still improve efficiency of compilation (with no effect on the product) by following the rules below:

- Don't include the same header twice at the source code level.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  ...40 other project specific includes...

  #include <stdio.h>
  ```

  (Yes, I've seen it in real code; I've fixed it, often.  And, as noted in the comments, it isn't an incredibly bad performance issue, but it is messy in the code.)
- Don't include headers that aren't needed.

Comment: Include guards can pretty trivially handle multiple includes of the same file. Removing redundant includes is more a matter of cleanup than any objective advantage.

Comment: Cleaning up does speed up compilation time. The best example of that is `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`. It really adds up for larger projects.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking what is the difference between having one big header and 5 small headers in code? When compiling the body of header is added at the place of "include" line so #include just modifies source code and does not make application slower when running. That does not affect performance but when making big project you will want multiple headers, instead of making big one, for same reason as not writing whole application in one source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to static headers that you include with `#include`, then there is no difference at run-time. The compiler will combine all the "information" in these headers into a single program.

Comment: What is a "static" header?

Comment: oops, my bad, I meant static libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you end up changing the order in which the headers are included, AND your headers are doing things which headers ought not to do (i.e. defining objects and not merely types and functions), then you could change memory locality and affect runtime performance.

Or, if you have redundant declarations of inline-defined functions (which is also not a great idea), and you reorder the headers so that the definition becomes visible to more or fewer call sites, then it's possible for runtime performance to change (although most optimizers should be able to inline upwards).

Note that if your code is subject to these changes, it's probably vulnerable to actual breakage, such as reordering changing the set of template specializations which are visible at the point of use.